# Changing value inside array to be editable input field

Tags: php, html

have a small problem. In this part of code:

```
<?php
 $data = [
    "eCheckDetails"=>[
    "paymentsReceived"=>$history["transactionSummary"]["eCheckTotal"],
    "revenueReported"=>$history["transactionSummary"]["eCheckTotal"],
    "fundsDeposited"=>$history["transactionSummary"]["eCheckTotal"],
    "accountAdjustment"=>0.00],

"paymentCardDetails"=>[
    "paymentsReceived"=> $history["transactionSummary"]["paymentCardTotal"],
    "revenueReported"=> $history["transactionSummary"]["paymentCardTotal"],
    "fundsDeposited"=>  $history["transactionSummary"]["paymentCardTotal"],
    "accountAdjustment"=>0]
  ];
```

data  " **$history [...][...]**"

is taken from another file or database (its not really important from where)

Point is, that this data is sometimes incorrect, and needs to be changed manually. And this is my question. How to make this fields (where $history [..] [..] is) editable, to be

```
           <input type="text">
```

(with small button ACCEPT or smg somewhere aside) with default value hidden under $history[..][..].
I tried to do it, but its inside array and didnt have any luck. Maybe someone knows?

Best regards

Comment: you can give name to your input fields in this form `<input type='text' name='history[1][23]' value='$val'>` and when you POST your form, PHP will get an array in $_POST['history']... i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use named keys in your HTML attributes, for example `<input ... name="history[transactionSummary][eCheckTotal]">`. Submitting this back to the server will fill your array.

```
<?php

$form = <<<EOS
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" value="" name="history[transactionSummary][eCheckTotal]">
    </form>
EOS;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    var_dump($_POST);
} else {
    echo $form;
}
```

The content of the `$_POST` superglobal will be:

```
Array
(
  [history] => Array
    (
      [transactionSummary] => Array
        (
          [eCheckTotal] => dsdsa
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you ! can you tell me one more thing? how this way send more than one input data. I mean i have to edit 8 of them, but hitting enter after filling all 8 inputs does nothing. Can it be done in one form?/without butonns/

Comment: This is a client side issue, how the data is presented in the browser. Most browsers will submit on Enter if you have the following `<form action="{something}" method="post"><input type="text" name="..."></form>`, however this assumes that you don't have any event handlers that might block it.